# Update a column that is similar to all tables - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

A this point I have a database with almost 1000 tables, several of them have a lat lng field and a user with a ID ( every table that has that lat lng has the ID field also ) has changed his location.

Now I have to update all the tables but I haven't designed this database ( basically I'm new at this job and my boss threw this hot bowl to me ) so I don't know even where to start.

Is there a way to change the data on every tables that have a latlng field and share this ID number ?

For example: if ID = 1024 and the table has a latlng cell, update that latlng cell to the new value.

Comment: Did you say you had a thousand tables?!

Comment: yes. at this point I don't know how many but they said to me that there qere 900 and a few tables on this database ( and I would go check on every single one )

Answer (score 0):

So, as this had some views, I'll post my solution :

In order to update all tables that share a id number ( for instance, I have one table for each service and the id and the address of every client that bought it at some point, one client had his location changed so ), in order to update this I made a php script that goes like this:

```
    <?php
    // connecting !
    $con =mysqli_connect("localhost","my_username","my_password","database");

    // convert code
    $showTables = mysqli_query($con,"SHOW TABLES");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showTables))
    {
    foreach ($row as $key => $table)
    {
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `". $table . "` SET `addres`='new_address' WHERE `id`= '27' "); 
        echo "UPDATE `". $table . "` SET `address`='new_address' WHERE `id`= '27' "; // for testing purposes - you can delete this!
    }
}
?>
```

This is it, it made me want to break the pc at some point but when you see it, it is simple!

Best regards.